# Rsync: Exclude files by maximum filename length (< 143 characters)

Tags: backup, rsync, exclude, ecryptfs

A cronjob copies files from a remote server (probably `ext4`) via `rsync` to a local encrypted partition (probably `eCryptFS` on top of `ext4`).

Now rsync throws errors for filenames that are longer than 143, which is expected due to the way filenames are encrypted on the target.

Since I can't change those parameters, I can't influence the files to be backed-up and there's only a handful of those that fail, I want to ignore / exclude the files in question.

I thought about running a `find` for files with names longer than 143 characters, writing to a temporary file and then using that as the `--exclude-from` for `rsync`.

But is there a more elegant and reliable way to do this I'm missing? I don't want the cronjob to skip more files than strictly necessary, but I also need it to run without errors to not trigger a monitoring alert.

Comment: I ended up using this `find` command to create a list of files to exclude https://stackoverflow.com/a/42944001 and wrote the list to a temporary file, then I used the `--exclude-from` option to reference the file when running `rsync`